# Value Error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

I am preparing s3dis data to be in hdf5 format but when it comes to a specific scene (Area1, hallway6 ) with size 210 MB it gives me error!
the relevant part of the code :

```
def sample_data(data, num_sample):
    """ data is in N x ...
        we want to keep num_samplexC of them.
        if N > num_sample, we will randomly keep num_sample of them.
        if N < num_sample, we will randomly duplicate samples.
    """
    N = data.shape[0]
    if (N == num_sample):
        return data, range(N)
    elif (N > num_sample):
        sample = np.random.choice(N, num_sample)
        return data[sample, ...], sample
    else:
        sample = np.random.choice(N, num_sample-N)
        dup_data = data[sample, ...]
        return np.concatenate([data, dup_data], 0), range(N), list(sample)

def sample_data_label(data, label, num_sample):
    new_data, sample_indices = sample_data(data, num_sample) #line 128
    new_label = label[sample_indices]
    return new_data, new_label
```

The error :

```
File "E:\Research\Codes\pointnet\pointnet-master\sem_seg\indoor3d_util.py", line 128, in sample_data_label
 new_data, sample_indices = sample_data(data, num_sample)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: In your `else`, you're returning three elements, so you can't unpack two.

Comment: Your recursive calls require `sample_data` to return exactly two values, but one of its `return` statements returns three (the one in the `else` clause).  Change it to return two.

Comment: then what should I do?! the previous scenes had no problem as they weren't the case of the last (else), how could I solve this error?

Comment: ps: the original script was like that : return np.concatenate([data, dup_data], 0), range(N)+list(sample) ..... I removed the (+) as it showed error that this was not applicable and replaced it with a comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final else block has 3 items (`return np.concatenate([data, dup_data], 0), range(N), list(sample)`)

1: `p.concatenate([data, dup_data], 0)`
2: `range(N)`
3: `list(sample)`

Comment: Then what should I do?! the previous scenes had no problem as they weren't the case of the last (else), how could I solve this error?

Comment: Change that final else block so you're returning 2 objects, and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved! It was returning three values instead of two, thanks for everyone helped.